# Test my code in a dummy file structure

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a python utility that uses locate command internally. It replaces file names with it's corresponding complete file path.

```
>>> complete_path('cd baz')
'cd foo/bar/baz'
```

How do I write a test corresponding to this functionality since output for this command would be variable on every system? Do I have to run this code in a fixed dummy file structure and then assert it's output with a fixed path? How to do that?

Comment: It depends on what testing framework you're using. But it sounds like an easy function to test. Monkeypatch your calls to the external libs you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your function looks like, but something like this would do it, if you're using pytest:

```
def test_complete_path(monkeypatch):
    def mockreturn(path):
        return 'cd /abc/def/g'

    monkeypatch.setattr(external_module, 'external_function', mockreturn)
    res = complete_path('cd g')
    assert res == 'cd /abc/def/g'
```

Have a look at http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html for more info.

Comment: As I understand it, this strategy assumes something about how the complete_path function is implemented, i.e. using the external_function from the external_module. If so, as soon as the implementation changes, the test will break. Is there no way to mock the "file system environment", to make the test independent of implementation?

Comment: @Fredrik The real goal would be to write `complete_path` in a way that doesn't require *any* file system. What does `locate` do? It provides a list of strings. You can write `complete_path` to take a command and a list of strings, and it becomes a pure function that is easily tested. Now the only implementation-specific knowledge you need is how `locate` gets called and its output parsed and passed to `complete_path`. (For example, maybe it's `p = Popen(["locate"], stdout=PIPE); complete_path(cmd, list(p.stdout))`). The I/O glue is probably small enough to not worry about abstracting over it.

Comment: @chepner I was trying to find the best way to test a function that does operate on a file system. Your proposal is to change the definition of the tested function and I don't see how I could generalize that in a useful way.

Comment: @Fredrik You'll have to post your own question; I can't answer that within the constraints of a comment.